# Load MapReduce output data into HBase

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, guava, classnotfoundexception, bulk-load

The last few days I've been experimenting with Hadoop. I'm running Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode on Ubuntu 12.10 and successfully executed some standard MapReduce jobs.

Next I wanted to start experimenting with HBase. I've installed HBase, played a bit in the shell. That all went fine so I wanted to experiment with HBase through a simple Java program. I wanted to import the output of one of the previous MapReduce jobs and load it into an HBase table. I've wrote a Mapper that should produce `HFileOutputFormat` files that should easily read into a HBase table.

Now, whenever I run the program (using: hadoop jar [compiled jar]) I get a `ClassNotFoundException`. The program seems unable to resolve `com.google.commons.primitives.Long`. Of course, I thought it was just a dependency missing but the JAR (Google's Guava) is there.

I've tried a lot of different things but can't seem to find a solution.

I attached the Exception that occurs and the most important classes. I would be truly appreciated if someone could help me out or give me some advice on where to look.

Kind regards,
Pieterjan

**ERROR**

```
12/12/13 09:02:54 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/12/13 09:03:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201212130304_0020
12/12/13 09:03:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/12/13 09:04:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/12/13 09:04:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201212130304_0020_r_000000_0,Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.primitives.Longs
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue$KVComparator.compare(KeyValue.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue$KVComparator.compare(KeyValue.java:1536)
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.PutSortReducer.reduce(PutSortReducer.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.PutSortReducer.reduce(PutSortReducer.java:40)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

**JAVA**
**Mapper:**

```
public class TestHBaseMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> {

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //Tab delimiter \t, white space delimiter: \\s+
    String[] s = value.toString().split("\t"); 
    Put put = new Put(s[0].getBytes());
    put.add("amount".getBytes(), "value".getBytes(), value.getBytes());      
    context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(s[0])), put);
}
```

**Job:**

```
public class TestHBaseRun extends Configured implements Tool {

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = getConf();

        Job hbasejob = new Job(configuration);
        hbasejob.setJobName("TestHBaseJob");
        hbasejob.setJarByClass(TestHBaseRun.class);

        //Specifies the InputFormat and the path.
        hbasejob.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(hbasejob, new Path("/hadoopdir/user/data/output/test/"));

        //Set Mapper, MapperOutputKey and MapperOutputValue classes.
        hbasejob.setMapperClass(TestHBaseMapper.class);
        hbasejob.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
        hbasejob.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);

        //Specifies the OutputFormat and the path. If The path exists it's reinitialized.
        //In this case HFiles, that can be imported into HBase, are produced.
        hbasejob.setOutputFormatClass(HFileOutputFormat.class);
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
        Path outputpath = new Path("/hadoopdir/user/data/hbase/table/");
        fs.delete(outputpath, true);
        HFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(hbasejob, outputpath);

        //Check if table exists in HBase and creates it if necessary.
        HBaseUtil util = new HBaseUtil(configuration);
        if (!util.exists("test")) {
            util.createTable("test", new String[]{"amount"});
        }

        //Reads the existing (or thus newly created) table.
        Configuration hbaseconfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create(configuration);
        HTable table = new HTable(hbaseconfiguration, "test");

        //Write HFiles to disk. Autoconfigures partitioner and reducer.
        HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(hbasejob, table);

        boolean success = hbasejob.waitForCompletion(true);

        //Load generated files into table.
        LoadIncrementalHFiles loader;
        loader = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(hbaseconfiguration);
        loader.doBulkLoad(outputpath, table);

        return success ? 0 : 1;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ClassNotFoundException*, it means that the required .jar that contains com.google.common.primitives.Longs cannot be found.

There are several ways to solve this issue:

- If you're just playing with Hadoop, the simplest way to solve this issue is to copy the required .jar into */usr/share/hadoop/lib*.
- Add the path to the required .jar to `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. To do so open */etc/hbase/hbase-env.sh* and add:

  export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="<jar_files>:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH"
- Create a folder */lib* in your root project folder. Copy your .jar into that folder. Create a package (.jar) for your project. The result will be a fat jar contained all the jars included in */lib*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had the JAR as a dependency in my project so it was in the /lib folder but that didn't work. Neither just letting the JAR in hbase/lib (it's an HBase dependency) did work. It was the second solution, adding it to Hadoop's classpath that solved the issue. I don't quite see what made the difference, but it works now.

Comment: An even easier way to get the class path is to use the following command: `hadoop classpath`