# Hbase read performance varying abnormally

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I've installed HBase 0.94.0. I had to improve my read performance through scan. I've inserted random 100000 records.

When I set `setCache(100);` my performance was 16 secs for 100000 records.

When I set it to `setCache(50)` my performance was 90 secs for 100000 records.

When I set it to `setCache(10);` my performance was 16 secs for 100000 records

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    long start, middle, end;

    HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor("Student7");
    descriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("No"));
    descriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Subject"));

    try {   
    HBaseConfiguration config = new HBaseConfiguration();
    HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);

    admin.createTable(descriptor);
            HTable table = new HTable(config, "Student7");
            System.out.println("Table created !");

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i =1;i<100000;i++) {
        String s=Integer.toString(i);
        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(s));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("No"), Bytes.toBytes("IDCARD"),Bytes.toBytes("i+10"));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("No"), Bytes.toBytes("PHONE"),Bytes.toBytes("i+20"));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("No"), Bytes.toBytes("PAN"),Bytes.toBytes("i+30"));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("No"), Bytes.toBytes("ACCT"),Bytes.toBytes("i+40"));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("Subject"), Bytes.toBytes("English"),Bytes.toBytes("50"));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("Subject"), Bytes.toBytes("Science"),Bytes.toBytes("60"));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("Subject"), Bytes.toBytes("History"),Bytes.toBytes("70"));

        table.put(p);
    }
    middle = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Scan s = new Scan();
    s.setCaching(100);      
    ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(s);

    try {
        for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr=scanner.next()) {
            System.out.println("Found row: " + rr);
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }       
        System.out.println("TableCreation-Time: " + (middle - start));
        System.out.println("Scan-Time: " + (middle - end));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOError: cannot create Table.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you use the same random records in all 3 tests, or did you generate the random records new for each test?

Comment: Same records for all three cases. I just varied the parameter to 100,50, and 10 and executed the code.

Comment: Did you rerun your test to ensure that the values are stable?

Comment: I just read this and your previous post. Can you please provide your schema and your complete `Scan` or `Get` code? I struggled with the same thing a while back mainly due to a badly designed schema. At the moment I'm running a cluster with 3 very old laptops, a table with 605 million records and I'm able to get my results (around 100 records) in 0.020 seconds.

Comment: Yes. All the attributes have the same value for every test.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Can you tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to return every record in your 100000 records table? You're doing a full 
table scan and just as in any large database this is slow.

Try thinking about a more useful use case in which you would like to return some columns of a record or a range of records.

HBase does only have one index on it's table, the row key. Make use of that. Try defining your row key so that you can get the data you need just by specifying the row key.

Let's say you would like to know the value of `Subject:History` for the rows with a 
row key between 80000 and 80100. (Note that `setCaching(100)` means HBase will fetch 100 records per RPC and is this case thus one. Fetching 100 rows obviously requires more memory opposed to fetching, let's say, one row. Keep that in mind in a large multi-user environment.)

```
Long start, end;
start = System.currentTimeMillis();

Scan s = new Scan(String.valueOf(80000).getBytes(), String.valueOf(80100).getBytes());
s.setCaching(100);
s.addColumn("Subject".getBytes(), "History".getBytes());

ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(s);
try {
    for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr=scanner.next()) {
        System.out.println("Found row: " + new String(rr.getRow(), "UTF-8") + " value: " + new String(rr.getValue("Subject".getBytes(), "History".getBytes()), "UTF-8")));
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
} finally {
    scanner.close();
}       
System.out.println("Scan: " + (end - start));
```

This might look stupid because how would you know which rows you need just by an integer? Well, exactly, but that's why you need to design a row key according to what you're about to query instead of just using an incremental value as you would in a traditional database.

Try this example. It should be fast.

Note: I didn't run the example. I just typed it here. Maybe there are some small syntax errors you should correct but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: I get it @Pieterjan.  Thanks for your answer. It was helpful. But lets say, if want to scan all 100000 records , why is my performance varying each time for different setCaching() values? I don't get the point.

Comment: Did you try it multiple times with the same `setCaching()` value and does it always take as long? Because I most say this indeed doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes for the same setCaching() values(for 100,lets say) it takes 15-16 secs always. I'm just trying to check the performance for a full table scan.

Comment: Why it does take longer with `setCaching(50)` as with `setCacthing(10)`, I can't say. That just doesn't make sense. But if I were you, I would stop thinking about full table scans. These make no sense in an HBase environment. A full table scan will always be slow in HBase. HBase wasn't designed for that. Now it takes 15 seconds but this is for 100000 rows. Try to imagine that with a real HBase table in which you'll probably have 20000 times that amount of rows.

Comment: How do i insert 605 million records?(As you mentioned earlier). How do i do bulk loads. Can you please provide me with your code? It would be of great help for me.

Comment: Basically it comes down to writing a mapper that produces files of the type `HFileOutputFormat`. Then you can bulk load this output using the `LoadIncrementalHFiles` class. Some test code I wrote earlier is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863382/load-mapreduce-output-data-into-hbase. Also have a look at http://hbase.apache.org/book/arch.bulk.load.html. It's pretty well explained there. Bulk loading works really fast. I did load this 605 million rows in around 20 seconds.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24114/discussion-between-suresh-hadoop-and-pieterjan)