# How to Set In-Memory in HBase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I've HBase 0.94.0 up and running on top my HDFS 0.20.0. I'm doing my homework where i have to put my column families in `In-Memory` I have two column families No and Subject.

After setting them to `In-Memory`

```
new HColumnDescriptor("No").setInMemory(true);
new HColumnDescriptor("Subject").setInMemory(true);
```

When i check my `localhost:60010`, the table details still shows `IN_MEMORY => 'false'` Why is this happening? Do i have to more than setting just `.setInMemory(true)`

Comment: that should actually work. could you show me your code?

Comment: @Tariq Here is my code. I've posted it in my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729779/hbase-read-performance-varying-abnormally/14730543#comment20640568_14730543

Answer (score 1):

```
HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor("Student92");
    HColumnDescriptor col1=new HColumnDescriptor("No".getBytes());
    HColumnDescriptor col2=new HColumnDescriptor("Subject".getBytes());
    col1.setInMemory(true);
    col2.setInMemory(true);
```

This worked !